# Sharing $scope data between angular js and non angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-scope

In the AngularJS, `$scope.mydata` contains some data with in the controller. I'm using JSP (normal JSP page) with out any AngularJS functionality,But I want the data with in the scope variable (mydata) which contains in the controller.  How can I retrieve the data with in the scope variable in my jsp page.
Can anybody sugest this..

Comment: What you want to do with retrived data? You can have some `JavaScript` function declarated in JSP. Than call this function and pass `$scope.mydata` as argument.

Comment: Yes,There is Javascript function declared in my jsp. Is this scope available in anywhere in the jsp page?

Comment: This is just variable – pass is as argument to your method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a variable in top of app.js in angular stater project. Just make it clear may this sample code help you base on angular tabs starter project:

```
// in app.js
var myShareData;
...
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

// in controller.js
...
.controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope, Friends) {
  $scope.friends = Friends.all();
  myShareData = Friends.all();
  // or 
  // myShareData = $scope.friends;
})
```

Now you can use `myShareData` at any where on your non angular js. Off course you need check `myShareData` has value or not before you can use it.

Comment: But how can i include jsp(jsp page contains with out any  angular tags) in the controller.so that only sharing is possible right? can u please give simple example

Comment: You can define `myShareData` in your jsp. Forget about `var myShareData;' in `app.js` but place it on your jsp page and in angular controller, assignment the `myShareData` with value.